Combination lock on a pentagonal rotating table
This puzzle is part of a serie.

Inspiration: Sliding Bolt Puzzle
Part 1: Combination lock on a triangular rotating table

Puzzle
After solving the 3 digits code in 27 tries (again, you just have the worst luck possible), you open the door and finally find some light. But you are not free! It is just a new room that looks exactly like the previous one, except this time the table is inlaid with 5 rotary dials in a regular pentagonal arrangement. The dials have 5 position each, and the code is 00000 again. But wait, can't you see the numbers this time? Upon closer inspection, the numbers are totally worn down, the rotary dials are just blank at this point. You wonder if someone got stuck here long enough to erase these numbers just by trying to escape. You think about keeping an eye on the table while checking the door, to keep track of the table rotation, but the door is behind a turn of the wall. It seems like the light brought you hope and comfort but nothing else...
Just like the previous time, you start to think of a strategy to get the code to 00000 without seeing the numbers and without knowing the rotation of the table. This time there is 55 = 3125 possibilities, so it will take a while.
Bonus question: Just in case this trend continues, you start wondering how you would solve the same situation if there was p rotary dials with p different symbols on it, where p is prime. (Other cases will be covered in part 3)
Rules clarification
There is no tricks or lateral thinking in this puzzle, you can only alternate between:

Modifying the code, with an increment VWXYZ: V for the first dial, W for the second, and so on, and if a digit goes over 4 it cycles back to 0
Going to the door to test if it is the correct code ABCDE = 00000, but meanwhile the code can rotate from ABCDE to BCDEA, CDEAB, DEABC, EABCD or ABCDE.

You have to find a surefire strategy; you can't rely on your luck.
Hints
This puzzle may look like the same as part one (just more tedious) but the added complexity is just enough to motivate a new insight on this problem.
The beautiful solution found below is quite a step-up from the solution in part 1, so I'm adding some hints to try and bridge that gap, in hope a wider range of people can enjoy this problem and it's solution.
Hint 1:

 Start small, can you get to code 00000 if you know the starting position is in a easy subset of all positions?

Hint 2:

 If you have a subset S of positions that you know how to solve (for example all positions of the form AAAAA), is there a sequence outside of S that you can bring into S in just one move ? If yes, you can solve a larger subset, and then do that again!

Hint 3:

 If you are stuck with the sequence A1A2A3A4A5, consider the sequence of increments around the circle: B1B2B3B4B5 where B1 = A2 - A1, B2 = A3 - A2, ..., B5 = A1 - A5.

Hint 4:

 Maybe you can choose A1A2A3A4A5 so that you know how to solve the sequence of increments B1B2B3B4B5. If the sequence of increments goes to 00000, that means A1A2A3A4A5 goes to a constant sequence, of the form AAAAA. Iterating on this idea should be enough to solve all sequences.


Golly gee, there's only 129 classes of states to consider...

I could try to add a hint, I have a solution far more elegant and concise (absolutely not coming close to considering 129 classes of states). It is quite mathematical though.

For what it's worth, I can certainly confirm that there is a satisfying structural approach to these that does not involve any grinding.

My procedure is:

          Perform one Level 4 sequence, which is defined by:


          Level 0 Sequence:
              (Check door; Modify 11111) x 5

          Level 1 sequence:
              (Level 0 sequence; Modify 01234) x 5

          Level 2 sequence:
              (Level 1 sequence; Modify 01441) x 5

          Level 3 sequence:
              (Level 2 sequence; Modify 01324) x 5

          Level 4 sequence:
              (Level 3 sequence; Modify 01111) x 5


 The pattern for these modification steps is that at level $L$ dial
 $j$ is turned $j^L$ steps. So $01441$ may be written $0, 1, 4, 9, 16 \pmod{5}$,
 $01324$ may be written $0, 1, 8, 27, 64 \pmod{5}$, and
 $01111$ may be written $0, 1, 16, 81, 256 \pmod{5}$. This should generalize easily to other primes.

For the proof, first some setup ignoring the rotations:

 The modification used in the level $L$ subsequence corresponds to the
 function $f_L: x \mapsto x^L$ on $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$,
 interpreted as “Turn dial $j$ by $f_L(j)$ steps.”


 Applying two or more of these functions (with no rotations in
 between) clearly composes linearly. “Modify 01324, then 11111, then
 01324” corresponds to $2 f_3 + f_0 = x \mapsto 2 x^3 + 1$. Sequences
 of these operations can then generate any polynomial of degree $\le 4$.


 Also, since 5 is prime, all polynomials of degree $\le 4$ in
 $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}[x]$ are distinct. This is a trivial
 consequence of the existence of the field $GF(5^5)$.


 There are $5^5=3125$ of these functions. Since each function is
 distinct on $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$, each function will have a
 different effect on the initial dial configuration, and one of those effects must be to solve it. The goal, therefore,
 is to prove that each one of these functions is applied to the dials
 and tested.

The main claim:

 Suppose the dials have been modified from their initial state by some
 sequence of modifications corresponding to function $m$. Applying a
 level $L$ sequence does two things: 1) test $m + f$ for every $f$ a
 degree $\le L$ polynomial, and 2) change dial state to $m + g$ for
 $g$ a degree $< L$ polynomial (and rotate the table).


 If this claim is correct, then: the initial modification function is
 $x \mapsto 0$.


  - After the first Level 0 sequence, all functions of the form
    $x\mapsto N$ will be tested.


  - After the first Level 1 sequence, all functions of the form
    $x\mapsto N + Mx$ will have been tested, and the current dial state will be
    the initial state modified by some $x \mapsto N$.


  - After the first level 2 sequence, all functions of the
    form $x\mapsto N+Mx+Ox^2$ will have been tested, and the current dial state
    will be the initial state modified by some $x \mapsto N+Mx$.


  - And so on...


 So when level 4 is finished, all 3125 functions of the form
 $N+Mx+Ox^2+Px^3+Qx^4$ will have been tested on the initial
 combination, one of which will have changed it to 00000.

Now to address the rotations:

 The table is rotated in an unknown way at the beginning, and since I
 check between every modification the rotation changes between each
 one. Viewing rotation as $r_n : j \mapsto j + n$ on
 $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$, each modification is therefore composed
 with a random rotation.


 So “Modify 01441, rotate, Modify 01441” actually corresponds to
 $x\mapsto x^2 + (x + N)^2$ for an unknown $N$. This differs from
 “Modify 01441 twice”, but only by $2Nx+N^2$, a degree 1 function.


 For example, “Modify 01234; Level 0; Modify 01234” within level 1
 does not always modify by 01234 + 01234 = 02413. But it always
 modifies by one of 02413, 13024, 24130, 30241, or 41302, and these
 only differ by some $N \cdot $ 11111.

 Similarly, “Modify 01441, Level 1, Modify 01441” will not always
 result in modifying by 02332, but the discrepancy will always be of
 the form $N\cdot\text{11111}+M\cdot\text{01234}$.

To prove the claim,

 The Level 0 sequence clearly satisfies this. Applying 11111 and
 checking, repeated five times, will check every possible adjustment
 of the dials that does not differentiate between dials (constant
 functions) and leave them in the state they started at.


 Inductively, within a level $L$ sequence every “Level $L-1$” step
 applies a degree $\le L-1$ polynomial and a rotation. So each “Level
 $L-1$; Modify” step applies $(\text{lower-order terms}) + (x + N)^L$
 which is $x^L + (\text{lower-order terms})$.


 After five such steps, then, the effect on the dials is
 $5x^L+(\text{lower order terms})$ and the $5x^L$ vanishes. This is
 part 2 of the claim.


 By induction, the first of five steps checked all functions of the
 form $m+0x^L+(\text{lower order terms})$, the second step checked all
 of the form $m+1x^L+(\text{lower order terms})$, and so on. So all 5
 steps will test all 5 possible coefficients in degree $L$, which is
 part 1 of the claim.

Other thoughts:

 The state of the dials is an element of $\mathbb{F}_5[x]/(x^5-1)$,
 and the goal is to change it to $0$. Rotation by $N$ is
 multiplication by $x^N$. Applying $VWXYZ$ is adding
 $V+Wx+Xx^2+Yx^3+Zx^4$.

 The modification 11111 corresponds to $a_0=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4$, and
 $(x-1)a_0=x^5-1=0\in\langle 0\rangle$; the element $(x-1)$ expresses
 ambiguity of unknown rotations and $a_0$ has no ambiguity. The
 modification 01234 corresponds to $a_1=x+2x^2+3x^3+4x^4$, and
 $(x-1)a_1\in\langle{a_0}\rangle$; $a_1$ is rotation-unambiguous up to
 $a_0$. And so on.


 This would seem to recast the problem in terms of finding a sequence
 of ideals, or of generating elements, satisfying certain properties.
 If the entire ring could be built this way, then every
 initial combination of dials could be solved. However, from that perspective I'd have a hard time specifying the requirements for such elements/ideals, proving their existence, or constructing them.


Awesome answer, and just as intended (-: Did you make an account just for this problem ? I'm really glad it got the great answer it deserved, maybe even better!

Thanks! I posted my solution partly because it feels as though it skirts a general concept that I can't see; maybe someone can point to the missing pieces of my thoughts interpreting this via F_5[x]/(P).

That's a very nice solution sgilles! I found that a helpful way to view this structure is as the group ring $\mathbb{F}_5[C_5]$ rather than a quotient of the polynomial ring (even though these amount to the same thing here). From this perspective, it is perhaps easier to see the exact demands on the chain of ideals that you are trying to construct for the solution (not going to spell it out though, in case you want to keep thinking yourself).

Thanks, that suggestion is really helpful. I've not had time to work through it fully, but it maps much more clearly to the problem as specified than my first attempt.
